# Laravel Observer Create Working but Delete Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am Trying to Using Observer for Deleting With Relationship But Problem Is When i DD in Created Function Its Working Fine But When i DD In Deleted Function It Shows Nothing (POSTMAN)  Means Neither Working Nor Error With Same Everything

Here Is Api:

```
$api->post('store','App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@store');
$api->delete('delete/{id}','App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController@destroy');
```

Here Is Observer file made by artisan

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Customer;

class CustomerObserver
{
    public function created(Customer $customer)
    {
        dd($customer);  
    }

    public function deleted(Customer $customer)
    {
        dd($customer); 
    }
}
```

Here is Customer Controller

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        return Customer::store($request->person);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
       $delete = Customer::where('person_id',$id);
       $delete->delete();
    }
}
```

Here Is Customer Model File.

```
class Customer extends Model
{
    //Relationship Start From Here
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
    }

    //End Here

    public static function store($request)
    {
        //Call to Person Model And Save User
        $user = Person::store($request);

        //Create object of Customer Model
        $customer = new Customer();
        $customer->fill($request['customers']);
        $customer->person()->associate($user)->save();

        //return customer 
        return $customer;
    }
}
```

Comment: after `deleted` there is no `customer` to `dd()`

Comment: Thanks For reply .. i also tried this but same no response if i DD in CustomerServiceProvider then show DD...  public static function boot() 
    {
        dd(1);
        Customer::observe(CustomerObserver::class);
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you do all things

1  add  line in `Customer::observe(CustomerObserver::class);` in CustomerServiceProvider in `boot` method

2. add `CustomerServiceProvider` in app.php file in provider array
3. `composer dump-autoload`
4. `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: changed but problem is same anyother way to check weather this function is working or not..... if then write code for other models

         public function deleting(Customer $customer)
         {
                 dd($customer); 
         }

Comment: i tried with PersonObserver with Person Model But there also same problem

Comment: thanks sir its done sorry for being late updated ...... i used config:cache and use softdeletes

Comment: @Minkzsingh no problem bro

Answer (score 10):

I know this might be a late reply and not sure if you are still looking for the answer. I think the issue is about how you delete your `Customer` model.

When you do something like

```php
$delete = Customer::where('person_id',$id);
$delete->delete();
```

You are executing a mass delete statement. As stated in [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#deleting-models), `mass deletes will not fire any model events for the models that are deleted` This is the reason your `deleted` observer event didn't fire.

> When executing a mass delete statement via Eloquent, the deleting and deleted model events will not be fired for the deleted models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when executing the delete statement

Now look at how you create a `Customer`. You create a model one at a time. Therefore your `created` observer does get run.

```php
//Create object of Customer Model
$customer = new Customer();
$customer->fill($request['customers']);
$customer->person()->associate($user)->save();
```

To solve your problem, the easiest way is to retrieve all the models and delete one by one, so that you can trigger the event.

```php
foreach (Customer::where('person_id',$id)->get() as $delete) {
   $delete->delete();
}
```

Comment: The documentation (as of 9.x) does not make it clear that not only event listeners but also observers will fail for mass deletes. -_- Thanks so much for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this problem, however I was calling the delete method from the repository, which prevents the Observer's deleted event from being triggered. When I used the delete from the mode it worked normally.

Answer (score 1):

Only these Methods Works

```
$customer=Customer::where('id',$id)->first();
   if($customer){
          $customer->delete();
      }

Or 

    $customer=Customer::find($id)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel observers are used to monitor and respond to specific events that occur in your application's Eloquent models. When it comes to using observers with soft deletes in Laravel, there are a couple of things to keep in mind.

1- Import the ***Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes*** trait: Before using observers with soft deletes, make sure that your model is using the SoftDeletes trait provided by Laravel. This trait adds the necessary methods and attributes to enable soft delete functionality.

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    // ...
}
```

2- Register the observer: To use an observer, you need to register it with your model. This can be done in the boot method of your model or in the booted method of a service provider.

```
use App\Observers\YourModelObserver;

class YourModel extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        YourModel::observe(YourModelObserver::class);
    }

    // ...
}
```

3- Observer implementation: In your observer class, you can define methods to handle the specific events you want to observe. For soft deletes, you can use the deleting and deleted events.

```
namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\YourModel;

class YourModelObserver
{
    public function deleting(YourModel $model)
    {
        // This method is called before the model is deleted (soft or hard delete)
    }

    public function deleted(YourModel $model)
    {
        // This method is called after the model is deleted (soft or hard delete)
    }
}
```

Make sure you have implemented the above steps correctly. If you're still facing issues with your observer not working with soft deletes, please provide more specific details or code examples that can help identify the problem.