# laravel : in observer how to fired detach method for pivot table?

Tags: laravel, observers

I implemented 3 table :`product` , `shop` and `product_shop` for pivot.

in the pivot table I have 4 column: `id` , `product_id` , `shop_id` , `product_count`.

and I made an observer for `ProductShop` model , but the `deleted` method not fired !

should I create `detached` method for pivot observer ?

Comment: The event names are `deleting` and `deleted` there's no `delete` event. Can you share your code?

Comment: yes it is deleted, but never run

Comment: How are you deleting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677194/laravel-observer-create-working-but-delete-not-working

Comment: I deleted by `$shop->products()->detach();`

Comment: That's a mass delete so will not fire any events. If you want events to file you'd need to retrieve and delete each pivot element individually

Comment: @apokryfos
do you mean I have to make `foreach` on `$shop->products` and detach one by one pivot rows ?

Comment: Something like `foreach ($shop->products as $product) { $product->pivot->delete(); }` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  created a `foreach` on `$shop->products` and detach one by one pivot rows, it's work! and `deleted` method fired correctly.

```
foreach($shop->products as $product){
        $shop->products()->detach($product->id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

pivot table don't need to model.
to add pivot use `attach`, when creating a product and i'm need to add to a shop just use `attach` like: `$product->my_relation_to_pivot()->attach(id of shop or array of ids shops);`

for update use `sync`, like: `$product->my_relation_to_pivot()->sync(id of shop or array of ids shops)`
note: this method will delete all ids in database where not in array or int value you passed to him.

for delete use `detach`, like: `$product->my_relation_to_pivot()->detach()` will delete all records with `product_id` equal `$product->id`

Comment: Yes, generally pivot table don't need to model, but in this case I have to made an observer for pivot table, so I have to made model for it.